# Python, swap variables every loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, swap

I have part of code that looks like this:

```
for i in [0,1]:
    ...
    print('{} used {} words that {} did not use.'.format(a[i], 50 , a[i+1]))
```

For the first iteration, I want it to do,

```
print('{} used {} words that {} did not use.'.format(a[0], 50 , a[1]))
```

but for the second iteration, I want this:

```
print('{} used {} words that {} did not use.'.format(a[1], 50 , a[0]))
```

How can this be done?

Comment: `1 - i` is one option.

Comment: `(i+1)%2` is another

Comment: `i ^ 1` also works

Comment: I don't think it's really clear what is being asked here. How should the desired solution generalize to longer loops, for example iterating over `[0,1,2,3,4]`? Or, Eric, is `[0,1]` the only case you want to handle? If so, why not just write two `print()` statements and be done with it?

Comment: I’d say that if it’s only two items then remove the loop for readability.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the indice modulo 2 (`%2`):

```
a = ['first', 'second']

for idx in [0, 1]:
    print('{} used {} words that {} did not use.'.format(a[idx%2], 50 , a[(idx+1)%2]))
```

#### output:

```
first used 50 words that second did not use.
second used 50 words that first did not use.
```

#### Alternatively, if only two items:

it *might* be easier to read and maintain to do like this:

```
a = ['first', 'second']
x, y = a
print('{} used {} words that {} did not use.'.format(x, 50 , y))
print('{} used {} words that {} did not use.'.format(y, 50 , x))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the modulous operator `%`:

```
for i in [0,1]:
    ...
    print('{} used {} words that {} did not use.'.format(a[i % 2], 50 , a[(i + 1) % 2]))
```

On the first iteration, `i = 0`:

```
i % 2       == 0 % 2 == 0
(i + 1) % 2 == 1 % 2 == 1
```

On the second iteration, `i = 1`:

```
i % 2       == 1 % 2 == 1
(i + 1) % 2 == 2 % 2 == 0
```

Note that the first `i % 2 == i` for this particular instance of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If that is exactly what you're looking for, you could do:

```
for i in [0,1]:
    ...
    print('{} used {} words that {} did not use.'.format(a[i], 50 , a[(i+1)%2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
a = ['John','Doe']
amount = 50

# Use index to create strings to be formatted
s1 = '{0} used {2} words that {1} did not use.'
s2 = '{1} used {2} words that {0} did not use.'

print(s1.format(*a,amount))
print(s2.format(*a,amount))
```

Returns:

```
John used 50 words that Doe did not use.
Doe used 50 words that John did not use.
```

Or :

```
# Use index to create strings to be formatted
s = '''\
{0} used {2} words that {1} did not use.
{1} used {2} words that {0} did not use.'''

print(s.format(*a,amount))
```

Returns:

```
John used 50 words that Doe did not use.
Doe used 50 words that John did not use.
```